# Geode DUnit Inter-VM communication

Tags: locking, semaphore, orchestration, geode

I am implementing geode dunit based tests.Each VM executes Callable asynchronously.The logic is having several steps , between which the VMs need to be synced up. Its not possible to separate them into several different callable s because some variables need to be persisted between stages.

Currently the VMs are doing sleep after each stage and this way the VMs are synced. However i am looking for another option which would allow execution without sleep ( semaphore based ).

Is there an option to have a shared resource between VMs that would allow to sync up the VMs , or may be some geode based mechanism that would allow such orchestration of VMs?

BR

Yulian Oifa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geode's internal testing framework does this in several places, actually, I'd suggest having a look at the [geode-dunit](https://github.com/apache/geode/tree/develop/geode-dunit) project for examples, specially at the [Blackboard](https://github.com/apache/geode/blob/develop/geode-dunit/src/main/java/org/apache/geode/test/dunit/Blackboard.java) java class.
Cheers.

Comment: Thanks , thats what i was looking for